# Google Apps Script : set a formula and then copy/paste the value

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd just need a script that would set a formula in a cell and then copy/paste the value in the same cell (or in another cell, no matter). Exemple below : here I just need to set a "=max(A3:A)+1" formula in cell A2, then copy cell A2, then paste values only in A2. Tried to record a macro, so I have this code :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=max(A3:A)+1');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Does not work… When googling this I found I may have to write cache buffering, so I read some stuff about CacheService, but I'm not sure and don't know how to use it anyway…

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because you are trying to read the value before the sheet is updated. You could try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before the last line, but it's best to do the whole calculation in Apps Script; something like this should do the job:

```js
const maxValue = spreadsheet.getRange('a1:a3').getValues()
  .reduce((max, item) => item[0] > max ? item[0] : max, -Infinity)
```

Then you can insert the `maxValue` wherever you need.

Comment: agreed, cleaner to do the calculation in the function rather than pushing it to the sheet to be calculated and then replacing it

Comment: Thx a lot Dmitry, SpreadsheetApp.flush() works fine anyway… Now I'll try the cleaner method and let you know.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, calculation in Apps Script is working as well, may I ask you how to add 1 to the value (as my formula was "=max(A3:A)+1"). And if possible I would like to insert the current date, so I would need an in-app calculation for today() formula…